# Creating the perfect resume - Anyway to put some sort of markdown in a resume that hides clipboard copy?

Tags: clipboard, html, markup

**Note: not looking for a speicifc language implementation, just want to get poiinted in the right direction**

This question is very broad and not specific and I probably will get downvoted for it but was curious:

Is there any way for me to programmatically create a webpage depicting a resume, such that when copy and pasted only some portions of it get copied to the clipboard?

We all know the situation where you have your resume with a header like:

```
Name
_____________________________
```

Where that line seperator looks good on the resume, but on many modern applications it pulls info from the resume and autofills it and the line then looks messed up.

Is there any sort of solution, maybe some sort of markup of what can get copied to the clipboard or not?

Comment: Does it have to be STRICTLY HTML or can jQuery be used?

Comment: Any language, just wanted to get pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. In one div, write the information you want to be copied separated by spaces and `<br />` only. In a second div, write the nice formatting like your line separator, then use CSS to position the 2nd div over the first one. Or just wrap every formatting elements in a div and make them have `user-select: none;`

For example, see this:

```css
#myinfo{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  position:absolute;
}

#fancy {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  position:absolute;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="myinfo">
  <span>
  Bob Tables
  </span> <br />
  <span>Engineer</span>
  </div>
  <div id="fancy">__________</div>
</div>
```

Now I'm not saying this is a good idea, you can probably achieve what you want without superposing two div as long as it's something CSS can do.

Comment: I now realise this question is about 1.5 years old. Not sure how I ended up here..